# Can't insert data to mysql, fatal error encountered

Tags: c#, mysql

To be honest i just got interested in programming and this is my first project and i am stucked. So i created dinamical textboxes and i want to save information to the database, but fatal error pops up every time. I know that connection is correct. i know the problem is with  dinamical textboxes, searched threw internet, didn't found solution, sorry for bad english, hope you can help me.

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
        textbox1.Size = new Size(75,23);
        textbox1.Text = "Pav.";
        textbox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        panel1.Controls.Add(textbox1);
        string name = textbox1.Text;

        TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
        textbox2.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        textbox2.Text = "0.5";
        textbox2.Location = new Point(80, 0);
        panel1.Controls.Add(textbox2);
        float sum = float.Parse(textbox2.Text);

        ComboBox comboBox4 = new ComboBox();
        comboBox4.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        comboBox4.Text = "-Type-";
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Salary");
        comboBox4.Location = new Point(170, 0);
        comboBox4.Items.Add("Other");
        comboBox4.Name = "comboBox4";
        panel1.Controls.Add(comboBox4);



        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Save";
        btn.Location = new Point(250, 0);
        btn.Click += delegate 
        {
            if (comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Salary")
            {
                string myConnection = "datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=root";
                string insert = "insert into budget.incomes (Name, sum) values (@Name, @sum);";
                MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
                MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(insert, conDataBase);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                try
                {
                    conDataBase.Open();
                    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                    this.Close();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    { }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: `sum` is a keyword but you also did not supply any values for those parameters so it has no idea *what* to insert

Comment: A numericUpDown control is probably a better choice to edit a float.

Comment: And you should post the errors your getting because we're just guessing your problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the DataReader and you need to use parameters.

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=root";
string insert = "insert into budget.incomes (Name, sum) values (@Name, @sum);";

using (var conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
using (var cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(insert, conDataBase))
{       
    cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sum", sum);
    conDataBase.Open();
    cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved");       
}
this.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you, now everything is fine. i used DataReader just becouse of tutorial on youtube.

Comment: Yes, i took a minute to think about it, that tutorial was about registration and login form, so he used DataReader. nevermind, one lesson at the time, most important is progress :D